# ListPlot with gradient

Tags: plotting, functions, function-construction, legending

I have a dataset in which each element is a list of 3 numbers eg.

```
data={{0,0,0},{1,2,0.7},{3,4,2.3},{3,4,3.3}}
```

I'd like to make a 2 dimensional plot in this way: for each list in the dataset the first 2 elements specify the point coordinate in the 2D plot and the third element specifies a color taken from a color gradient (for example using `ColorData[]`), so that close numbers have close colors; moreover, I'd like to show a bar legend with colors.

An example that solve the problem is this

```
mM=MinMax@data[[All,3]]
dataPoints=Tooltip[{Blend[{Red,Blue},Rescale[#[[3]],mM]],Point[{#[[1]],#[[2]]}]},#[[3]]]&/@data
Legended[Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[10],dataPoints},Frame->True],BarLegend[{Blend[{Red,Blue},#]&,mM},ColorFunctionScaling->True]]
```

Apart that maybe there is a bug in the frontend, since it says that «`ColorFunctionScaling` is not an option for `BarLegend`», can I obtain such a plot without using the `Graphics` command and related primitives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 0.7}, {3, 4, 2.3}, {3, 4, 3.3}};

mM = MinMax@data[[All, 3]];

cf = Blend[{Red, Blue}, Rescale[#, mM]] &;

dataPoints = Tooltip[{cf[#[[3]]], Point[Most@#]}, #[[3]]] & /@ data;

Legended[Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[10], dataPoints}, Frame -> True],
  BarLegend[{cf, mM}]]
```

[image]

Note that two of your points are at the same coordinates `{3, 4}` and only the last will show. You could change your color function to `cf = Blend[{Opacity[0.5, Red], Opacity[0.5, Blue]}, Rescale[#, mM]] &;` then overlapped points will be darker than singular points. However, in general the colors would then be washed out.

**EDIT:** Using [`ListPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html)

```
dataPoints = Tooltip[Style[Most@#, cf[#[[3]]]], #[[3]]] & /@ data;

Legended[
 ListPlot[dataPoints,
  PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[10],
  Frame -> True],
 BarLegend[{cf, mM}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Well, you've improved my answer but I was looking for an approach different from what I've done. For example, a specific Mathematica function would be a perfect solution. Note that other languages provide such functions. I'll modify my question to be more specific. Thanks anyway :)